# Truncating date objects on Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

When my website shows a snippet of a blog post through any widget, it displays the featured image, the title, the first characters of the text itself and the *date the post was made*.

Inside Wordpress' content.php, it shows the date using *the_time()*, like this:

```html
<div class="date-box">
     <div class="day"><?php the_time('d'); ?></div>
     <div class="month"><?php the_time('M'); ?></div>
</div>
```

The parameter 'M' passed in the function the_time() is supposed to give PHP the month written with only 3 characters (January would be JAN, February would be FEB and so on).
In my native language (which is portuguese) it gets the months, obviously, in portuguese: January is *Janeiro*, February is *Fevereiro*... which doesn't matter for *the_time('M')*, it truncates it the same way.

My problem is that the month May is *Maio* in portuguese, a 4-letter month. Upon passing it to PHP, for some obscure reason, it *doesn't get truncated*. It keeps it *Maio*, which obviously [prejudices my layout.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQjPX.png)
I'm not a PHP developer, but I did a little research and tried a workaround inside the content.php, but it doesn't work:

```php
<div class="month">
<?php
    $t = the_time('M');
    if(strlen($t) > 3){
       echo mb_strimwidth($t, 0, 3);
    }else{
       echo $t;
    };
?></div>
```

It might even be syntax issues, because I really don't know PHP, but it seems that I might need it to solve this problem. Am I going the right way here? I appreciate any help you give me!

TL;DR: I need to truncate a 4-letter date into a 3-letter one and pass it back to HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress' `the_*()` functions all `echo` their output directly and don't return anything, so you can't assign the value to a variable. You're looking for [`get_the_time()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_time/).

The rest of your code looks like it should work just fine.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I knew I was missing something in the documentation! :D